# Regex for measurement in hands

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

Horses in the US are typically measured in [hands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_%28unit%29) and inches. A hand is basically just 4 inches. So if a horse was say 62 inches. he would be 15.2 hands tall NOT 15.5. This is because the portion to the right of the decimal is really the remaining inches less than 4, a fraction of a whole hand expressed as a decimal.

Or to be more concise, the portion to the right of the decimal point can only be a single digit that is either a 1, a 2 or a 3. The portion on the left should be a positive integer. The measurement could also just be a whole positive integer if, for example the horses measurement in inches was a multiple of 4.

I am pretty much a dummy on RegEx and I was unable to find an example of this on line and my attempts to modify ones that seem close have ended in failure :)

These are examples of matches: `15.1`, `9.2`, `100.3`, `16`

These are examples of non-matches: `15.10`, `15.01`, `19.4`, `-15.1`, `16.0`

Oh and one last thing. I will b using this for validation using JavaScript and perhaps C# as well.

Comment: Why does this question seems an April Fools? :-)

Comment: This seems like a highly confusing format.  Imagine if we wrote 5 hours 30 minutes as 5.30 instead of 5:30 or 5.5 hours.  I have no idea if there is a standard format of hands and inches, but 5h2' or maybe separate text boxes if this is for a UI. seems better than 5.2.  Or just standardize to hands as in 5.5 hands.  Multiple by 4 to translate to inches.  It just seems better that way to me.

Comment: lol, I know. highly confusing. But horse people get it. I have seen it written 15-2, 15h2 pr even 15hh2. (the hh stands for hands high) but I wanted to stay true to the official unit spec: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_%28unit%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is `^[0-9]+(\.[1-3])?$`

in js:

```
var rx = /^[0-9]+(\.[1-3])?$/;
```

in c#

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[1-3])?$");
```

Comment: But this allows for leading zeros.  So it would match `001.1`.  The OP didn't have an example like that, so maybe that's OK but should be noted.  Changing the `[0-9]+` to `[1-9][0-9]*` would fix that if needed.

Comment: Although I guess you would want to allow `0.1`, `0.2`, and `0.3`.  So maybe `^(0\.[1-3])|([1-9][0-9]*(\.[1-3])?)$`

Answer (score 2):

If you're only able to have an integer or an integer followed by `.1`, `.2` or `.3`, you could do that with something like:

```
\d+(\.[123])?
```

with appropriate `\b` (or `^`/`$`) boundary markers at the ends, depending on the method you're using to match (whole string or partial).

If you don't want true internationalised digits, you could replace `\d+` with something like `[1-9][0-9]*` instead.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\d` in a C# regex (*and perhaps C# as well*) It will match Unicode digits like `٠١٢٣`, and I still have to see a program where it is useful.

Comment: @xanatos: because _you_ have never found it useful, doesn't mean it's not useful. It's self-centric/culture-centric thinking like that, that causes problems in the internationalisation arena. I would think, as an Italian, you'd be more sensitive to such issues, with your quaint swapping of decimal point and comma :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm very sensitive to persons that say that diacritics are "special" characters, but I do think a number is a number, and I don't think I would like to see a DB with heights in ten different digit formats. If someone wants to use the arabic-indic digits, he will use them with `[٠-٩]`. And then the point is that `\d` has different meaning in .NET and Javascript (unless you use an option in .NET to use the Ecmascript version of Regex)

Comment: But never mind, I'll provide an option for the non-internationalised possibility as well.